# Using CSS Media queries to hide a fixed element on zoom

Tags: css

I have fixed positions elements that I would like to hide on zoom (especially on mobile) using the following css:

```
@media (max-width: 300px){ .hide {display: none;} }
```

This works with desktop Chrome & IE10 (eg at ~400% zoom, the elements are not displayed) , however it doesn't work with FF34 or on mobile (android browser or Chrome).

I also tried

```
@media (max-width: 20em){ .hide {display: none;} }
```

and had the same issue.

It seems that zoom affects each browser width differently and I am looking for a work around.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px){
 .hide {display: none;} 
}
```